# Read CSV as dataframe and convert to JSON string

Tags: scala, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

I'm trying to aggregate a CSV file via Spark SQL and then show the result as JSON:

```
val people = sqlContext.read().format("com.databricks.spark.csv").option("header", "true").option("inferSchema", "true").option("delimiter", ",").load("/tmp/people.csv")  
people.registerTempTable("people")  
val result = sqlContext.sql("select country, count(*) as cnt from people group by country")
```

That's where I'm stuck. I can to a `result.schema().prettyJson()` which works flawlessly, but I don't find a way to return the `result` as JSON.

I was assuming that `result.toJSON.collect()` should do what I desire, but this fails with a

```
org.apache.spark.SparkException: Job aborted due to stage failure: Task 1 in stage 101.0 failed 1 times, most recent failure: Lost task 1.0 in stage 101.0 (TID 159, localhost): java.lang.NegativeArraySizeException
    at com.databricks.spark.csv.CsvRelation$$anonfun$buildScan$6.apply(CsvRelation.scala:171)
    at com.databricks.spark.csv.CsvRelation$$anonfun$buildScan$6.apply(CsvRelation.scala:162)
    at scala.collection.Iterator$$anon$13.hasNext(Iterator.scala:371)
    at scala.collection.Iterator$$anon$11.hasNext(Iterator.scala:327)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.aggregate.TungstenAggregationIterator.processInputs(TungstenAggregationIterator.scala:511)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.aggregate.TungstenAggregationIterator.<init>(TungstenAggregationIterator.scala:686)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.aggregate.TungstenAggregate$$anonfun$doExecute$1$$anonfun$2.apply(TungstenAggregate.scala:95)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.aggregate.TungstenAggregate$$anonfun$doExecute$1$$anonfun$2.apply(TungstenAggregate.scala:86)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD$$anonfun$mapPartitions$1$$anonfun$apply$20.apply(RDD.scala:704)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD$$anonfun$mapPartitions$1$$anonfun$apply$20.apply(RDD.scala:704)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.MapPartitionsRDD.compute(MapPartitionsRDD.scala:38)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.computeOrReadCheckpoint(RDD.scala:300)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.iterator(RDD.scala:264)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.MapPartitionsRDD.compute(MapPartitionsRDD.scala:38)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.computeOrReadCheckpoint(RDD.scala:300)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.iterator(RDD.scala:264)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.ShuffleMapTask.runTask(ShuffleMapTask.scala:73)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.ShuffleMapTask.runTask(ShuffleMapTask.scala:41)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.Task.run(Task.scala:88)
    at org.apache.spark.executor.Executor$TaskRunner.run(Executor.scala:214)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
```

error. Can somebody guide me?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Turns out this error was because of a "malformed" CSV file. It contained some rows which had more columns than others (with no header field name)... Strange error message though.

Comment: Indeed, but one can only accept own answers after two days

Comment: It turns out this will happen even if the file is well formed but the schema you specify doesn't have enough fields.  I just encountered it with a file that had an extra comma at the end of each line, and solved it by adding an extra string field to the schema.

Comment: Additionally, it seems this this has nothing to do with JSON. It seems to me that anything you do that actually forces the query to run will hit this.

Comment: Well, I used the inferSchema option, so I didn't specify a schema myself.

Answer (score 2):

The error you're getting is odd, it sounds like result is probably empty?

You might want to try this command on the dataframe to get each line printed out instead:

```
result.toJSON.foreach(println)
```

See the [Dataframe API](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/scala/index.html#org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrame) for a little more information

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I'm search for a way to receive a complete `Dataframe` as single JSON. What you're suggesting would print each `Row` as JSON, if I understand correctly (Spark/Scala beginner here...)

Comment: It would yes, does it output anything? As I say, I think your result is probably empty at the moment based on the error you're getting. result.toJSON.collect() should return something like this based on the spark people.json test file:  Array[String] = Array({"name":"Andy","cnt":1}, {"name":"Michael","cnt":1}, {"name":"Justin","cnt":1})

Comment: I can do a `people.show()` but not a `result.show()`

Comment: The joy of Spark, every error message is strange :) glad you've sorted it

Answer (score 1):

Try

```
val people = sqlContext.read().format("com.databricks.spark.csv")
  .option("header", "true")
  .option("inferSchema", "true")
  .option("mode", "DROPMALFORMED")
  .option("delimiter", ",")
  .load("/tmp/people.csv")  
people.registerTempTable("people")  
val result = sqlContext.sql("select country, count(*) as cnt from people group by country")
```